# What does "in copy" mean in the following sentence?

Tags: meaning

> All documents should be attached to the visa application **in copy**.
>   Original documents should be submitted, too. They will be returned with the 
>   passport.

What does **in copy** mean here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't find a reference for *in copy* but this looks to mean ...

> **A photocopy of all documents** should be attached to the visa application. Original documents should be submitted, too. They will be returned with the passport.